# How to rewrite URL when using s3 for root domain?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, static, cloudflare

domain.com is an s3 static site on the root.
my.domain.com is a WordPress site on AWS.
Using Cloudflare for CDN.

How rewrite/redirect or masking URLs my.domain.com/test > domain.com/test?

Comment: Sorry just to clarify - is your whole domain - domain.com in cloudflare, with an a-record for domain.com that points to s3, and my.domain.com which points to wordpress? And you want to redirect anyone who goes to my.domain.com/test to domain.com/test?

Answer (score 0):

For URL masking via cloudflare, workers is the best option.

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/url-masking-question/55513/25